# Sorting a vector of custom class doesn't iterate over the vector correctly

Tags: c++, class, sorting, graphics, iteration

I am trying to implement a painters sort algorithm for a rendering assignment. The premise of the code is that I need to find the average depth of a polygon, and the list of polygons via the depth assigned to them by the for loop.

this is the polygons declaration, as well as a collection of the vertices of the polygon post transformation which are used for the calculation of the depth of the polygon

```cpp
std::vector<Polygon3D> _polygons;
std::vector<Vertex> _transvertices;
```

This is the method called by the model class to sort the _polygons vector using std::sort

```cpp
void Model::Sort()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= GetPolygonCount(); i++)
    {
        _polygons[i].SetDepth((_transvertices[_polygons[i].GetIndex(0)].Get(2) + _transvertices[_polygons[i].GetIndex(1)].Get(2) + _transvertices[_polygons[i].GetIndex(2)].Get(2)) / 3);
    }

    sort(_polygons.begin(), _polygons.end(), sortByDepth);

}
```

This code then links to this binary predicate

```cpp
bool sortByDepth(const Polygon3D &lhs, const Polygon3D &rhs)
{
    float m = lhs.GetDepth(); //For value testing
    float n = rhs.GetDepth(); //For value testing
    return lhs.GetDepth() > rhs.GetDepth();
}
```

The issue is, once the sort algorithm starts, the value of lhs and rhs never change - lhs always has a depth of 0 (and looking further into its assignment, it seems to be creating an entirely new polygon?) and rhs always has a value of 30.53 (the depth of the first polygon in the _polygons vertex

I'm concerned that the issue might be with not having a form of iterator linked to the Polygon3D class, but I wouldn't know where to start with making an iterator for the class.

Any help would be appreciated, I've looked through *far too many* similar questions, but none of them seem to be quite right for my particular problem.

EDIT:

Post got taken down because I didn't provide enough code apparently. I tried to reproduce the problem in a different project but for some reason it iterates just fine there.

This is the "shortest possible reproduction" I tried, but for some reason this doesn't seem to have the same issue as the original.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class Polygon3D
{
public:
    Polygon3D(); // Example data for testing purposes
    float GetDepth() const;
    void SetDepth(float depth);
private:
    float _depthAverage;
};

class Model
{
public:
    Model();
    size_t GetPolygonCount() const;
    void Sort();
private:
    std::vector<Polygon3D> _polygons;
    std::vector<int> _vertices;
    std::vector<int> _transvertices;
};


Polygon3D::Polygon3D()
{
    //_depthAverage = float(rand() % 100);
}

float Polygon3D::GetDepth() const
{
    return _depthAverage;
}

void Polygon3D::SetDepth(float depth)
{
    _depthAverage = depth;
}

Model::Model()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        _polygons.push_back(Polygon3D());
    }

    this->Sort();
}

size_t Model::GetPolygonCount() const
{
    return _polygons.size() - 1;
}

bool sortByDepth(const Polygon3D& lhs, const Polygon3D& rhs)
{
    float m = lhs.GetDepth();
    float n = rhs.GetDepth();
    return lhs.GetDepth() > rhs.GetDepth();
}

void Model::Sort()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= GetPolygonCount(); i++)
    {
        _polygons[i].SetDepth(float(rand() % 100) / 3);
    }

    sort(_polygons.begin(), _polygons.end(), sortByDepth);

}

int main()
{
    Model m = Model();
}
```

Edit 2:

I played around with just using an auto type variable to manually iterate over _polygons, and that seems to work. I dont understand why std::sort *doesnt*

```cpp
auto begin = _polygons.begin();

    while(true)
    {
        begin++;
    }
```

Comment: `i <= GetPolygonCount()` - just for my own sanity, why not use an iterator over `_polygons` . More to the same point, if `GetPolygonCount()` is effectively synonymous with `_polygons.size()` then your loop breaches your container high limit.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **[edit]** your question with an [mre] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Is it possible the compiler is confusing `std::sort` with a `sort` you defined? Did you check that the depths are correct before the sort? How many polygons do you have? Also the loop setting the depth should have `i < GetPolygonCount()`.

Comment: The assignment is for school - I've been instructed to make the GetPolygonCount() method and use the std::sort method, so i cant just write my own sort method to solve this. And i checked, but the std::sort is definitely the one in use.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be something incredibly stupid on my own part. The issue was the copy constructor used within the Polygon3D class - I had forgotten to copy over the depth value in the copy constructor, which meant lhs did not get a depth value.